# PHP oci_fetch_array returns only untill the first space

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to execute a cursor. It works fine, but if db returns date with spaces (i.e. `10.10.2013 9:30`) I'm getting only the first part (till the first space, i.e. `10.10.2013`. I wish to get the whole result.

Here the code snippet:

```
function exec_cur($conn, $mycursor, $outrefc)
{
        $ret = @ociexecute($mycursor); // Execute function
        $ret = @ociexecute($outrefc); // Execute cursor

        $i=0;
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($outrefc)) {
                foreach (array_keys($row) as $key)
                {
                        $row[$key]= str_replace(',', '.', "$row[$key]")  ;
                        $res[$i]["o_".strtolower ($key)] = "$row[$key]";
                }
                $i++;
        }
        oci_free_statement($outrefc);
        oci_free_statement($mycursor);
        @OCILogoff($conn);

        return $res;

}
```